# How to get a mouse cursor on screen?

Tags: usb-peripherals, mouse

I can get the mouse to work with my phone just fine; attach it through a simple adapter. Clicks register, movement registers - but I have to guess where the click will land, because there's no cursor.

How can I get the phone to display the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you're using Android 4.0 or later. Just go to Settings > Developer Options > Show Pointer location (or Show touches, whichever works) and toggle that on.

Note: If you don't see the developer options, you need to go to Settings > About Phone and tap on Build number several times.

Comment: This will cover my current situation. But I have another phone with older Android (and not enough room for upgrade), and I'd most welcome a solution for it too.